# Log4Net to Oracle -> PatternLayout fails with "converterType is null"

Tags: powershell, log4net

I'm running 15 parallel Powershell processes so I can't log to a file, and I can't flood the Application Event viewer. Logging to a database makes perfect sense. My problem seems to be a common one, but the only solution I've found is to hand code the Log4Net implementation rather than setting up a straightforward config file. This sounds wrong to me. I can't imagine there's no way around this config issue, but perhaps someone can point me to a more complete answer.

Full discussion of the issue exists at:
[Social.Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/604400d5-3383-421a-8b62-716280a82232/)

My config is per Apache specs for Oracle 9 databases:  [Apache Config Docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)

The first parameter uses the RawTimeStampLayout and works like a charm. The second parameter attempts to use the PatternLayout and fails.

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value=":log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <parameterName value=":message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

When I attempt to add a message using PatternLayout, I receive:

```
log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Could not create Appender  [AdoNetAppender_Oracle] of type [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender]. 
Reported error follows.
System.ArgumentNullException: CreateConverterInstance cannot create instance, converterType is null
Parameter name: converterType
```

Exactly like everyone else, if I use the RawPropertyLayout instead of PatternLayout I no longer receive the error, but I only log NULLs for those fields.

Per the discussion on Social.Technet, one way to make the logging work is to use code to create the parameters like this:

```
$param2 = New-Object log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter
$param2.ParameterName = "@log_level"
$parm2Layout=New-Object log4net.Layout.PatternLayout("%level")
$param2.Layout = New-Object log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter($parm2Layout)
$param2.DbType = "String"
$param2.Size = 50
$sqlAppender.AddParameter($param2)
```

Note that the PatternLayout is created then manually fed to the 2RawLayout Adapter. This seems to be the step missing in the config conversion process.

Does anyone know of a better way? Does anyone have a working PowerShell-Log4Net-Oracle config laying around?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you can't log to a file? There's a [`+MinimalLock`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#FileAppender) configuration for `FileAppender` that has log4net only taking locks while appending. The log4net file appender is damn [fast](http://anthonymastrean.tumblr.com/post/5895391929/measuring-high-performance-appending), too.

Comment: Good point, Anthony. I think I ended up with a solution similar to this - 15 different files worked just fine - but I was really hoping to get the entries into a DB. Life went on. I'll leave the question unanswered, since I'm still hoping to hear about the log4net implementation.